# How to have zombies spawn in day time like they do at night

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I already have a mod that lets them not burn, but I need something that lets them spawn in the day time so I can make a zombie apocalypse. I need help

Comment: You have to tell us more... Is this vanilla, modded, spigot, bukkit? And what have you tried so far?

Comment: I'm going to guess modded because you said mod, but a mod could also be considered a bukkit plugin!

Comment: You want to be careful with this, because requesting suggestions for other mods is off-topic here. This is achievable using in-game functions, making it on-topic however, so try to focus on that, and maybe edit your question to reflect that.

Comment: Its a mod called zombie sunscreen. They don't spawn in day though. I just need something that controls what mobs spawn in day and night. Even mobs from other mods.

Answer (score 1):

If you're in Creative Mode, you could use a Command Block and set this up to any type of clock:

```
/execute @a ~32 ~ ~32 /summon Zombie
```

This will spawn a Zombie 64 blocks away from all players (32 in the X axis, 32 i the Z axis.).

You could also set this up with a second one modifying the first command:

```
/execute @a ~4 ~ ~4 /summon Zombie
```

This will spawn a zombie 8 blocks away (4 in the X axis, 4 in the Z axis.).

Just set some Command Blocks up to a redstone clock and use these commands. You can modify the numbers so they spawn in different places. Just don't modify the middle number. That's how high they spawn.

Comment: Another option is summon the mob in and use /spreadplayers but targeting the zombie

Comment: No. Its not going to work the way I want it to work. I need them spawning in daytime like the do at night. I don't want them spawning in specific places. I want them spawning randomly.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that you are making an adventure map, you can use this great [Apocalypse Mod](http://mods.curse.com/mc-mods/minecraft/229199-apocalypse-mod) that I found on [Curse](https://www.curse.com/). The mod makes a lot more mobs spawn than on vanilla Minecraft. On top of the mod, you could also use hidden zombie spawners to spawn even more zombies.

For the mobs to spawn, you can set the time to night by making the player sleep or standing on a pressure plate, then resetting the time so that it is daylight. Or, you could just make the entire map nighttime and create a really creepy experience!

Comment: Not an adventure map. A normal Survival for me.

Comment: I cant configure that mod ether because Minecraft is a bitch.

Answer (score 0):

might be late but https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/in-control,
use https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/mob-inhibitor 's whitelist for allowing only zombies to spawn (if you type "zombie" it allows baby zombies too)

Comment: Hi Galaxius, welcome to Arqade! Late answers are definitely welcome, however it would be much more useful if you included a deeper explanation of what the links are and how they would help.

Comment: well i'm used to doing all stuff and figuring out myself that i forgot people need instructions yeah sorry, so for the first link there is a "config" folder in your prefered game profile location, go to it and you'll find "incontrol" go inside and edit with your notepad tool the "spawn.json" file and put this
[
{
    "result": "allow"
  }
]

Comment: for some reason there aren't spaces between them so i'll give you a link for the picture instead: http://prntscr.com/ow84bu
for the second link its really easy you just use forge's mod menu and go to incontrol and configure or whatever it says, and you enter to the whitelist and just type "zombie"